# VS.net 2008 Open Web Site hangs

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

I came across an issue in VS.net 2008 and VWD 2008 on Windows 7 where, when I open a File System Web Site the directory tree hangs for a minute or two.  But, it only happens on certain directories and once it returns to normal I'm able to open and close the directory that got stuck without issue.  Only if I close VS.net and reopen it does it hang again.

I think I pinpointed that the cause is I have 2 zip files in the directory that hangs.  The zip files are not large but they have thousands of files in them.  If I remove those zip files it seems to work ok.  I was thinking that maybe VS.net is trying to read the zip files, causing it to hang.

I didn't have time to see if I put those zip files in another directory it would cause that directory to hang, but I'll try later.

Has anyone come across an issue like this before?

Update:
It was due to the zip files.  I never had this problem before.  Not sure why it's there now.  Maybe Windows 7 handles something differently?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, had this a few times.

Do you have a virus scanner? If you do and exclude your project directories, it seems to fix a number of random problems such as these.

Comment: I do have a scanner, but it didn't seem to help with this issue.  I'm pretty sure now that it's due to the zip files I had in the directory because I made a new directory, put the zip files in there and the issue occurred on that directory.  Not sure why it happens.  I would guess that it's trying to read all the files in the zips.